# Is there a way to have a switch statement for an object with cases that validate if a key is present? - javascript

Tags: javascript, object, minecraft

**My goal:** Convert an if statement chain into a switch statement and have it waterfall down through the cases
**What I'm working with:** Decoded Minecraft NBT data (basically just an object)
**What my problem is:** I'm not sure if a switch statement would work for detecting if a key exists in an object, unless I do a ton of switch statements, but then it would be easier if I used a chain of if statements. 
**An example of an object would look something like this:**

```js
nbt = {
  type: 'compound',
  name: '',
  value: {
    i: {
      type: 'list',
      value: {
        type: 'compound',
        value: [
          {
            id: { type: 'short', value: 276 },
            Count: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
            tag: {
              type: 'compound',
              value: {
                Unbreakable: { type: 'byte', value: 1 },
                HideFlags: { type: 'int', value: 254 },
                display: {
                  type: 'compound',
                  value: {
                    Lore: {
                      type: 'list',
                      value: {
                        type: 'string',
                        value: [
                          '§7Damage: §c+35',
                          '',
                          '§7§8This item can be reforged!',
                          '§a§lUNCOMMON SWORD'
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    Name: { type: 'string', value: '§aDiamond Sword' }
                  }
                },
                ExtraAttributes: {
                  type: 'compound',
                  value: {
                    originTag: { type: 'string', value: 'CRAFTING_GRID_SHIFT' },
                    id: { type: 'string', value: 'DIAMOND_SWORD' },
                    uuid: {
                      type: 'string',
                      value: '3aa2d326-541f-4a2e-abae-04366b4771d3'
                    },
                    timestamp: { type: 'string', value: '6/1/21 8:44 PM' }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            Damage: { type: 'short', value: 0 }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**After this I remove some of the unnecessary keys, I get something like this:**

```js
{
  name: '§aDiamond Sword',
  lore: [
    '§7Damage: §c+35',
    '',
    '§7§8This item can be reforged!',
    '§a§lUNCOMMON SWORD'
  ],
  attributes: {
    rarity_upgrades: undefined,
    modifier: undefined,
    dungeon_item_level: undefined,
    dungeon_master_level: 0,
    hot_potato_count: undefined,
    fuming_potato_count: 0,
    art_of_war_count: undefined,
    enchantments: undefined,
    runes: undefined,
    ability_scroll: undefined,
    id: 'DIAMOND_SWORD'
  }
}
```

(Every item has different modifiers, some have runes and others don't, some items have special items like ability scrolls, however this item is completely clean and has nothing on it, which is why you see `undefined` for a lot of the fields. If an item doesn't have, say, ability scrolls, it just won't be in the NBT object.)
**The case statement I was envisioning looks something like this:**

```js
switch (item_schema) {
  case item_schema.attributes.fuming_potato_count > 10:
    console.log('Detected Fuming HPBs')
  case item_schema.attributes.dungeon_item_level > 5:
    console.log('Detected Master Stars')
  case typeof item_schema.attributes.ability_scroll !== 'undefined':
    console.log('Detected Necron\'s Blade Ability Scrolls')
  case typeof item_schema.attributes.enchantments !== 'undefined':
    console.log('Detected Enchantments')
  default:
    console.log('No Modifiers Detected')
}
```

Is this even possible to do? I just wanted to clean up my code and before this I just had a if statement chain, but I feel like this is probably a much simpler and cleaner way to do it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This will always output `No Modifiers Detected` even though modifiers are detected. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, I want it to print out the modifiers that are present, and not print the ones that aren't. With `switch (true)`, it seems to print everything though, and I'm trying to figure out why right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to consolidate your tests in an object, using a shorthand identifier

```
const cond = [
{'Detected Fuming HPBs': item_schema.attributes.fuming_potato_count > 10,
'Detected Master Stars': item_schema.attributes.dungeon_item_level > 5
}
```

.. and so on. Then you can just test for them where you need or loop through them for output

```js
let x = 3,
  y = 4
const cond = [
{'X is 4': x === 4},
{'X is less than 20': x < 20},
{'Y is 4': y === 4}
];

cond.forEach(obj => {
  const [output, condition] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  console.log(output, "? :: ", condition)
});
```

---

**Using `switch`**

You always want to run the switch, so set it to always process with `true` but the results might not be what you expect:

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures
> that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is
> executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If
> break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next
> statement in the switch statement. The break statement is not required
> if a return statement precedes it.

```
let hasCondition = false
switch (true) {
  case item_schema.attributes.fuming_potato_count > 10:
    console.log('Detected Fuming HPBs');
    hasCondition = true;
  case item_schema.attributes.dungeon_item_level > 5:
    console.log('Detected Master Stars')
    hasCondition = true;
  //case typeof item_schema.attributes.ability_scroll !== 'undefined':
  case item_schema.attributes.hasOwnProperty("ability_scroll"):
    console.log('Detected Necron\'s Blade Ability Scrolls')
    hasCondition = true;
  //case item_schema.attributes.enchantments !== 'undefined':
  case item_schema.attributes.hasOwnProperty("enchantments"):
    console.log('Detected Enchantments')
    hasCondition = true;
}
```

If you don't want to put `break;` statements after each `case:`,  you will need to process the `default` condition elsewhere since it will always run.

```
if (!hasCondition) console.log('No Modifiers Detected')
```

Taken from: https://dev.to/jasterix/using-a-switch-statement-with-logical-operators-17ni

Comment: Thx @A1rPun - I missed that. Updated to account for 'No conditions' condition.

Comment: @Kinglish I really like your answer because I've never seen this :) reminds me of pattern-matching

Comment: @Kinglish / @A1rPun - I've used your method for the no conditions condition, however it seems like the switch statement is just going into each case even though `typeof item_schema.attributes.ability_scroll !== 'undefined'` is false... From my understanding, it's comparing `true` to `typeof item_schema.attributes.ability_scroll !== 'undefined'`Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: AFPS - I updated my answer with alternate way of testing for undefined. Let me know if that helps

Comment: @afps It's because of the nature of a switch statement. When it finds a case which is true it will execute the code and ALL code beneath that case if there is no `break;` found. It will not reevaluate the case statement.

Comment: @Kinglish - It seems like it's still 'detecting' ability scrolls with that way of testing... I don't know what else is causing this... However, the first and second cases work.

Comment: @A1rPun - So there is no way of being able to test if every single case is valid? At this point, does it make sense to go back to a chain of if statements?

Comment: @afps Not in the way you were envisioning unfortunately. It makes sense to use ifs for your question IMO.

Comment: @afps - I added a new 'solution' in my answer, though I don't exactly know what you need these conditionals to do.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe do something like this using if statements:

```js
const item_schema = {
  name: '§aDiamond Sword',
  lore: [
    '§7Damage: §c+35',
    '',
    '§7§8This item can be reforged!',
    '§a§lUNCOMMON SWORD'
  ],
  attributes: {
    rarity_upgrades: undefined,
    modifier: undefined,
    dungeon_item_level: undefined,
    dungeon_master_level: 0,
    hot_potato_count: undefined,
    fuming_potato_count: 0,
    art_of_war_count: undefined,
    enchantments: undefined,
    runes: undefined,
    ability_scroll: undefined,
    id: 'DIAMOND_SWORD'
  }
}

const modifiers = [];

if (item_schema.attributes.fuming_potato_count > 10)
  modifiers.push('Detected Fuming HPBs')
if (item_schema.attributes.dungeon_item_level > 5)
  modifiers.push('Detected Master Stars')
if (typeof item_schema.attributes.ability_scroll !== 'undefined')
  modifiers.push('Detected Necron\'s Blade Ability Scrolls')
if (typeof item_schema.attributes.enchantments !== 'undefined')
  modifiers.push('Detected Enchantments')

if (modifiers.length)
  console.log(...modifiers)
else
  console.log('No Modifiers Detected')
```

If you have a lot of these you can look into a library that will help you validate schema's: [for example Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup).